# Better Bible Application Software (The Word/E-sword Replacement)

Tags: 12.04, gtk

Due to being un content of Bible software in Linux, two years ago I decided to code my Own. Unfortunately many commitments Development was stalled at early stages and still struggling. In Windows I have The Word and it is doing excellent. There is also e-sword which is excellent also. But in Linux the better I could find so far is Xiphos which is to be honest have ugly interface. Though it have powerful search capability it is lacking many features.

After bad experience with wine I want to avoid it at all costs so It is not option to run TW over wine. Is there any Bible study software for Linux with Dictionaries, Commentaries, Books and Bibles like TW with at least better interface. It should also be native in Unity/Gnome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Lucid or Maverick, you may want to try Bible Analyzer, as explained [here](http://www.bibleanalyzer.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=196#p698) (I suppose you could also find the source and compile/build it by yourself).

Alternatives are well listed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1935697).

Comment: I use Precise. I have added the tag. I'm having look at that. How Bible Analyzer compare to Xiphos?

Comment: You're asking too much... I'm not as interested into Bible...!

Answer (score 2):

An native Ubuntu Linux alternative for Bible study that does look pretty is BibleLightning, http://www.biblelightning.org/. It doesn't provide commentaries, but it is designed in such a way that you don't really need them. But it does offer a quarter million cross references.

Comment: I'm coding my own after being frustrated with whats there!